# How to connect more than one client socket to one server socket in Android?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I'm very amatuer on android and kotlin . I try to create socket connection , multi client try to connect one server then send and receive data.My server looks fine but when try to execute my example client it's returning `java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /10.0.2.16 (port 5000) from /:: (port 59694): connect failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)` error. What is the problem here?

What did i do wrong?

Here my Server running on service

```
class SocketService: Service() {

override fun onBind(intent: Intent?): IBinder? {
    return null
}


override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
    Thread{ ClientHandler().run() }

    return START_STICKY
}

internal inner class ClientHandler() : Runnable{
    override fun run() {
        try {
            ServerSocket(5000).use { serverSocket ->
                println("Server is listening on port " + 5000)
                while (true) {
                    val socket: Socket = serverSocket.accept()
                    println("New client connected")
                    ServerThread(socket).start()
                }
            }
        } catch (ex: IOException) {
            System.out.println("Server exception: $ex")
            Timber.e("$TAG $formatted $ex")
        }
    }

}

internal inner class ServerThread(socket: Socket) : Thread() {
    private var client: Socket = socket

    override fun run() {
        try {
            var reader = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()))
            var writer = PrintStream(client.getOutputStream())
            while (true) {
                receiveString = reader.readLine()

                val resCheck = checkMessage(receiveString)
                val ret = resCheck.split('-')[0]
                val retMessage = resCheck.split('-')[1]

                when (ret) {
                    "init" -> {
                        writer.write("$retMessage\n".toByteArray(Charsets.UTF_8))
                        writer.flush()
                    }
                    "error" -> {
                        writer.write("$retMessage\n".toByteArray(Charsets.UTF_8))
                        writer.flush()
                        println("error: $retMessage")
                    }
                    "pay" -> {
                        writer.write("$retMessage\n".toByteArray(Charsets.UTF_8))
                        writer.flush()
                        println("success")
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (ex: Exception) {
            Timber.e("$TAG $formatted $ex")
        }
    }
}
}
```

Here my client

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    Timber.plant(FileLog(applicationContext))

    SERVER_IP = resources.getString(R.string.IP)
    SERVER_PORT = resources.getString(R.string.PORT).toInt()

    thread { ThreadsendMessage("").run() }

}

private fun SendMessage(message: String) {
    thread { ThreadsendMessage(message).run() }
}

internal inner class ThreadsendMessage(private val message: String) : Runnable {
    override fun run() {

        if (socket == null){
            socket = Socket(SERVER_IP, SERVER_PORT)
            thread { ThreadsendMessage(message).run() }
        }
        else{
            if (!socket!!.isClosed){
                output = DataOutputStream(socket!!.getOutputStream())
                input = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(socket!!.getInputStream()))

                while (true){
                    output!!.writeBytes("$message\n")
                    output!!.flush()

                    rMessage = input!!.readLine()

                    runOnUiThread(Runnable {
                        textView.append("client: $rMessage\n")
                        textView.movementMethod = ScrollingMovementMethod()
                    })
                }

            }else{
                println("socket closed... ")
                var socket:Socket = Socket(SERVER_IP, SERVER_PORT)
                thread { ThreadsendMessage(message).run() }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your problem "more then one client" or "the first client cannot even connect"?

Comment: Where is your server running on? Where are your clients running on? Real Android device or emulator?

Comment: @blackapps I want to try with more than one client but when i try  "the first client cannot even connect" and i'm trying on emulator.

Comment: @blackapps both apps is in same emulator

Comment: The server code looks ok. Pretty standard. But you need to explain how your client code should work.

Comment: If both in the same emulator then ip 127.0.0.1 has to be used.

Comment: `I want to try with more than one client ` Unclear if they should run at the same time or one after another.

Comment: @blackapps client side is connect server send message and receive message thats all ok! Sorry for my english so do you have solution?

Comment: At the moment that is not all. Much too strange code. Solution? For what? I'm waiting for you to try 127.0.0.1. React!

Comment: @blackapps same error Connection refused

Comment: @blackapps but i guess i have problem in Server because when i debug server, it's not write in log println("Server is listening on port " + 5000) this

Comment: @blackapps i realised now

Comment: Put much more printlns in your server code to find out.